# Application generating "Error: listen EACCES" while starting application with pm2 on port 80?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, express, pm2

We are using pm2 for starting my nodejs app on port 80 on ubuntu. But the application generating error `**Error: listen EACCES**`. Our pm2 version is 0.12.7 and we are using the following command:

```
sudo pm2 start app.js -- dev
```

On running `whereis node` we get the following result:

```
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/sbin/node
```

We have already tried following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/sbin/node
```

Any idea where are we going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have another service already listening on port 80. try this:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

The output of this will tell you if any other process is currently using port 80.

Comment: 0.0.0.0:x              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1053/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::x                   :::*                    LISTEN      1053/sshd it is showing some thing like this